# Refreshing the Windows XP font cache via a script

Tags: windows, scripting

Does anyone know how to force windows XP to rebuild the list of installed fonts without needing a reboot.  They seem to have been installed correctly since everything works as expected after a reboot but I would like to avoid that reboot.

Comment: What method are you using now? Whenever I copy any font into the font folder it's immediately available to Word, etc. What are you using to determine that it's not available?

Comment: It had a better place on superuser.

Comment: I don't think superuser was around back when this question was asked.